# Save performance monitor counters?

Tags: windows-7, performance-monitor, perfmon

When I start Performance Monitor, I see a line graph with the default counter.

I am able to add additional counters without problems, and everything seems to work okay. However they are not "saved" between uses. I.e. I have to add and configure my counters every time I start Performance Monitor.

How do I make it so that my favorite counters are loaded automatically, and I can watch them in real time in the line graph?

Thanks.

Windows 7 Pro x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type `perfmon /sys` into run, whatever changes you make here should be saved on close. It also gives you the option to save and load in the file menu.

Ref: [How to save counters in perfmon tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388767/how-to-save-counters-in-perfmon-tool)

[image: Perfmon File Menu]